# How to find specific array elements in mongoDb document wih query and filter with range?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection which stores document in below format:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc1a108c5475b9e91bb7830"),
    "item" : "journal",
    "instock" : [ 
        {
            "warehouse" : "A",
            "qty" : 5.0
        }, 
        {
            "warehouse" : "C",
            "qty" : 15.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc1a108c5475b9e91bb7831"),
    "item" : "notebook",
    "instock" : [ 
        {
            "warehouse" : "C",
            "qty" : 5.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc1a108c5475b9e91bb7832"),
    "item" : "paper",
    "instock" : [ 
        {
            "warehouse" : "A",
            "qty" : 60.0
        }, 
        {
            "warehouse" : "B",
            "qty" : 15.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc1a108c5475b9e91bb7833"),
    "item" : "planner",
    "instock" : [ 
        {
            "warehouse" : "A",
            "qty" : 40.0
        }, 
        {
            "warehouse" : "B",
            "qty" : 5.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc1a108c5475b9e91bb7834"),
    "item" : "postcard",
    "instock" : [ 
        {
            "warehouse" : "B",
            "qty" : 15.0
        }, 
        {
            "warehouse" : "C",
            "qty" : 35.0
        },
        {
            "warehouse" : "M",
            "qty" : 50.0
        }
    ]
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cc1a16ea794ebd5fc278172"),
    "item" : "dig",
    "instock" : [ 
        {
            "warehouse" : "A",
            "qty" : 5.0
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find specific doc's array which has qty greater than specified value and less than the other specified value.

For e.g. I want item "postcard" and instock value greater than 10 and less than 40, so it return me the doc of postcard with instock array only containing one element which is matched like the output will be:

```
/* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cc1a108c5475b9e91bb7834"),
        "item" : "postcard",
        "instock" : [ 
            {
                "warehouse" : "B",
                "qty" : 15.0
            }, 
            {
                "warehouse" : "C",
                "qty" : 35.0
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I think the output you have mentioned is not correct, as per your question it should return only one element of "warehouse":"B"

Comment: yes previously the output was not correct but i have edited my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) for document level filtering and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to apply your condition on an array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { item: "postcard" }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            instock: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$instock",
                    cond: {
                        $and: [
                            { $gt: [ "$$this.qty", 10 ] },
                            { $lt: [ "$$this.qty", 30 ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Av0fEmdlLw4)